# Will TrueCrypt cause problems on a CrashPlan backup destination?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, crashplan

I recently began using my home computer as a remote backup destination for my "server" at work. I'm using CrashPlan, which is working quite nicely.

I also have my personal files on the same drive, and I recently installed TrueCrypt on it. I encrypted the entire partition in-place. I'm now wondering: in the situation that I need to restore my CrashPlan backup, will TrueCrypt have caused an issue, such as the data technically be encrypted twice? Do I risk anything becoming corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Encrypting the remote storage filesystem is transparent for Crashplan. It has no knowledge of the "low-level" on-disk data structure. It works on the filesystem level.

The only risk I see is if you forget your key or corrupt the truecrypt and then need to restore data stored there. The more component you add to a system, the more components are there that could theoretically fail.

Also don't forget that crashplan can backup to several destinations.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are facing is that the Truecrypt drive must be mounted and thus unencrypted while CrashPlan is running - so - you have no protection at that time.  If the Crashplan system is set to upload at a certain time, you could mount the TC drive at that time and then unmount it, but be aware that during that time, you are unprotected.

The other issue is that you can't expect the work blob of data to compress.  Encrypted data tends to be unencryptable.  Lastly, make sure you can't be subpoenad for the work info.  You don't want to have your personal data seizable and viewable if something happens at work.

Comment: This answer seems to answer a different question than the one asked.